# How to find the past 4 weeks of the same weekday value from date input string

Tags: sql, spring, spring-data-jpa

Am trying to select records based on date string ("2023-06-23") and the same day of each week for the last 4 weeks.

Today (Friday)

Last Friday

The Friday before that

The Friday before that

I need fetch records based input date string of last four weeks on same day because I am going to run this query every day so I don't want to use a between or something where I manually specify the date range.

Found solution on below query and its working based on system current date, here instead of current date how we can fetch records based on date input string

select * from table where DATE >= DATEADD(DAY, -21, CAST(GETDATE() AS DATE)) and Dept=979
and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE()) ORDER BY DATE DESC;

The above query is working fine in sqlserver db

Now the requiremnt is need to execute query using spring data jpa in  @Query
so in spring data jpa how can replace GETDATE() with input string date

Comment: Why don't you just say where `date = current_date OR date = current_date - 7 OR date = current_date -14 or date=current_date - 21`. Different database engines have different syntax for expressing `current_date` and subtracting days but you got the idea.

Comment: Replace getdate() in query above with variable. This looks like SQL Server syntax, so [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/HZ9KOGkJ) for SQL Server.

Comment: @Julian pls consider the input date is random one sometimes we may get the date like 2023-02-10 or 2023-01-12 like that. so whatever the input date based on this date I have to fetch records past 4 weeks.

Comment: @PonderStibbons actually the date is parameter input coming from java-spring data jpa side. after receiving the date input via in method need to append with sql query. Am agree with you and my questions is how we can include this date input in above query

Comment: I see. I can help only in SQL related part, but query works fine.

Comment: I still don't get it. If the date is variable you can still use `WHERE date = input_date OR date = input_date - 7 OR date = input_date -14 or date=input_date - 21`. Or maybe I don't understand the problem you are trying to solve

Answer (score -2):

To replace `GETDATE()` with an input string date in Spring Data JPA, you can modify the SQL query using a named parameter and pass the input date as a parameter to the query method. Here's an example:

1. Define a Spring Data JPA repository interface with a query method that uses the modified SQL query:

```java
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM MyEntity e WHERE e.date >= :startDate AND e.dept = 979 AND DAYOFWEEK(e.date) = DAYOFWEEK(:currentDate) ORDER BY e.date DESC")
    List<MyEntity> findByDateAndDeptAndWeekday(@Param("startDate") LocalDate startDate, @Param("currentDate") LocalDate currentDate);

}
```

2. Call the query method and pass the input date as a parameter:

```java
LocalDate inputDate = LocalDate.parse("2023-06-23");
LocalDate currentDate = LocalDate.now();

LocalDate lastWeek = currentDate.minusWeeks(1);
LocalDate weekBeforeLast = currentDate.minusWeeks(2);
LocalDate threeWeeksAgo = currentDate.minusWeeks(3);

List<MyEntity> result = myRepository.findByDateAndDeptAndWeekday(inputDate, lastWeek);
result.addAll(myRepository.findByDateAndDeptAndWeekday(inputDate, weekBeforeLast));
result.addAll(myRepository.findByDateAndDeptAndWeekday(inputDate, threeWeeksAgo));
```

Comment: based on the above approach modified use cases like below,

` @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "select af from MyEntity af where DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK, -4, CAST(GETDATE(=:date) AS DATE)) and DATE <= DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CAST(GETDATE(=:date) AS DATE))
            and DEPT_ID =:storeId and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE(=:date)) ORDER BY DATE DESC") `

Comment: passing inside GETDATE(=:date) date parameter and pls find the complete method on below  -  

ArrayList<MyEntity> getLastFourWeekRecordsByStoreByDate(@Param("storeId") Integer storeId, @Param("date") String date);

Comment: threw exception [Request processing failed: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC exception executing SQL [select af from MyEntity af where DATE >= DATEADD(WEEK, -4, CAST(GETDATE(= ?) AS DATE))
and DATE <= DATEADD(WEEK, -1, CAST(GETDATE(= ?) AS DATE))
and STORE_ID =?
and DATEPART(WEEKDAY, DATE) = DATEPART(WEEKDAY, GETDATE(= ?)) ORDER BY DATE DESC] [Incorrect syntax near '='.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]] with root cause

com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '='.

Comment: getting above exception now, could u let me know how to pass this date parameter in above query

Comment: Most or all of your six answers here appear likely to have been entirely or partially written by AI (e.g., ChatGPT).  Please be aware that [posting AI-generated content is not allowed here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it.

Comment: **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was generated by AI, please leave feedback accordingly. The moderation team can use your help to identify quality issues.